# Going over 12 columns: What's the harm?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have the requirement of taking a Json response formatting it so there are three items per row and how ever many rows there needs to be.

Besides being lazy and having to keep track of a counter, is there any negative effects to having one row with more than twelve columns since they will create a new line?

Even from the bootstrap documentation this doesn't sound like a bad idea

- If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.[[1](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)]

  ```
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>A</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>B</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>C</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>D</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>E</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>F</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>G</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
              <h3>H</h3>
              <p><a href="http://example.com">Link to project</a></p>
          </div>
      </div>
  ```

Comment: There's no harm, objectively speaking. Bootstrap 2 threw all kinds of conniptions if you did so, but version 3 handles it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in a 12-col grid per se, it just happens Bootstrap comes with a pre-built 12-column grid (arbitrary, but sensible default)

For an existing project, the potential harm is all the other UI elements expect a 12 column grid

In practical terms for your specific need, you probably want to make a custom UI element (i.e. a custom grid/"table" to display your data), and not really go make such a wide change like customizing the BS grids

If you're looking to change the grid, you can try recompiling all the CSS from the LESS source code and change the variables:

```
@grid-columns:              12;
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
```

Or use this customizer: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Where I am lost is the 'potential harm is all the other UI elements expect a 12 column grid' I don't see it, it seems the default BS3 now self adjust for this.  Apparently not BS2.  If I could make a custom UI, once I get the hand of it, would that help remove the need to keep track of the elements or would it still be required.  Today I can just use jQuery to create div hell.  But when playing around I didn't see the need with BS3.